# How to get the vertex id by knowing its value, assuming 4e6 nodes?

Tags: neo4j, dbpedia, gremlin

In DBPEDIA on top of NEO4J using a gremlin script.
I want to get in the fastest time the vertex id number of e.g.:

```
"@URI": "U http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States_Congress"
```

So what I tried to run is:

```
g.V.filter{it.v.value == "U http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States_Congress"}
```

### It takes too much time to be execute.

- How do I get the number of the node?
- How can I do it in real time system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're iterating over all vertices and filtering for a specific value.  That's bound to be slow!  Try looking up the value in the `value` key index instead:

```
g.V("value", "U http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States_Congress").id
```

Comment: It didn't work... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692776/why-g-vvalue-g-v32132-value-id-doesnt-work